# Students students=(FileRoutines.LoadStudents(STUDENT_FILE));

Tags: c#

I am taking a C# class and I have a project. The project has code written for void `Main()`. Here is the first part of the code in `Main()`:

```
const string STUDENT_FILE = @"C:\TEMP\Students.txt";
const string ASSIGNMENT_FILE = @"C:\Temp\Assignments.txt";
Students students=FileRoutines.LoadStudents(STUDENT_FILE));
```

I have to write a 3 classes Students, student, and FileRoutines. I cannot seem to figure out what needs to go into the Students class to get the instance to work. I can write the following:

```
string[] students = FileRoutine.LoadStudents(STUDENT_FILE)
```

and get the students array I am trying to do with:

```
Students students=FileRoutines.LoadStudents(STUDENT_FILE));
```

but I cannot seem to get this instance to work. This is the contents of the file:

```
122338  Weltzer Teresa
123123  Wang    Choo
123131  Adams   James
123132  Binkley Joshua Troy
123139  Howard  Tyler
123160  King    Alma
```

I have seen this project posted before, but no one seems to be able to answer the question, but instead offer other alternatives.
I know when creating an instance of a class I need to have a constructor or constructors, but I am not doing:

```
 Students students = new Students();
```

So far I am lost on what to do.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Consider a better title describing your problem. It would be really nice!

Comment: What isn't working with it? What does the `FileRoutine.LoadStudents` method look like?

Comment: @Joe It looks like he needs to implement it yet.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Perhaps, but how are we to know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

To implement as you ask, `FileRoutines.LoadStudents(STUDENT_FILE)` has to return a `Students` instance, so you need to modify that method to construct the new `Students` and return that instead of `string[]`

So perhaps your `Students` class takes the `string[]` in its constructor?

That should be enough to get you going?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the `Students` type has to behave like a collection of some kind. I propose this

A class for a student data is a piece of cake.

```
class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now things get a little more interesting. The following class implements `IEnumerable` of `Student` in order to provide the most crucial methods for looping through its inner structure. Is quite easy once you get this idea. You already store students in some collection so just return its enumerator instead of creating a custom one.

```
class Students : IEnumerable<Student>
{
    private readonly List<Student> students;

    public Students(IEnumerable<Student> students)
    {
        this.students = students.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Student> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return students.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return students.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And finally, a class with a method for loading from a file. This can be done many ways, but I find LINQ a nice tool for data querying.

```
class FileRoutines
{
    public static Students LoadStudents(string path)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
        var students = lines.Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                            .Select(split => new Student 
                             { 
                                 Id = split[0], 
                                 LastName = split[1], 
                                 FirstName = split[2] 
                             });
        return new Students(students);
    }
}
```